# Configure port for standalone Spring program

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How to configure port for standalone spring program. So that other instance of same program is not started?

Comment: This completely depends on how you're running your application in the first place.

Comment: Running as a bat or sh file. Having Java "programName" in it.